# problem in variables scope in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote this code

```
require('Database.class.php');



     function get_info (){



        $db = new Database($config['server'], $config['user'], $config['pass'], $config['database'], $config['tablePrefix']);
        $db->connect();


        $sql = $db->query('SELECT * FROM ja_cat');
        while ($options = $db->fetch_array($sql)) {

            $cat[].=" ".$options['title'];
        }
        $db->close();
        return $cat;
```

then I get this Mysql error

Mysql Error : No database selected .

but when I put the require instruction inside the function it's work fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make this the first line **IN** your get_info() function:

```
global $config;
```

Also, you may want to define $db outside of the function at the start of the code and then close the connection at the end, instead of having to re-connect multiple times.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is Database.class.php creates some variables that are probably global in scope that it relies upon. If you require it inside the function and it works, that supports that theory. Is that your class? Can you change it? Can you post it?

Basically $config needs a global qualifier inside the function.

Comment: here it is http://www.ricocheting.com/scripts/php_mysql_wrapper.php  , Andrew solved the problem

Comment: Ya he wrote out the reason and I wrote out the fix, I suppose I should have elaborated as to the WHY behind my HOW.

Answer (score 2):

You have to import the global variable `$config` into the scope of the function:

```
function get_info() {
    global $config;
}
```

Comment: You guys just don't see the problem? Isn't it?